# How to change BK color of DatePicker's Calendar

Tags: wpf, colors, background, datepicker

How to change the background color for a DatePicker's Calendar?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are speaking of the WPF Toolkit DatePicker from Microsoft, one possibility is to get the [source code](http://wpf.codeplex.com/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=25047) for the Toolkit and then modify the Generic.xaml theme file for the DatePicker. Add the Background property the DatePickerTextBox section of the DatePicker style like:

```
<primitives:DatePickerTextBox x:Name="PART_TextBox" 
    Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" 
    Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" 
    Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
    HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
    VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" />
```